# How to assign two conditions to if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm still a beginner and I'm trying use `||` as an "or" option but it won't work.

```
  @IBAction func RunCode1(sender: AnyObject) {
        if TextField1.text == "true" || "false" {
           Outcome1.text = "false"
            CorrectText.hidden = false
            Reason.hidden = false
            Continue1.hidden = false
    }
```

I want to do something when the textfield includes "true" or "false".

Comment: Just a note: properties, variables, method names, should begin with a lowercase letter. Beginning with uppercase letter is only for classes/structs/protocols/etc.

Comment: Il keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: @Boudz78 you can use my solution if you have to compare more than two text variable

Comment: Seems helpful in my case.. Thanks @khuong291

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to:

```
if TextField1.text == "true" || TextField1.text == "false"
```

Comment: This is correct! You have to remember that you can't say, for example, if textField.text == "true" || "false" ... because Xcode doesn't know what to look at to find "false"

Answer (score 2):

Another way :) :

```
if let text = TextField1.text where ["true", "false"].contains(text) {
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be:

```
 @IBAction func RunCode1(sender: AnyObject) {
        if TextField1.text == "true" || TextField1.text == "false" {
           Outcome1.text = "false"
            CorrectText.hidden = false
            Reason.hidden = false
            Continue1.hidden = false
    }
```